# using java.util.Scanner class in AndroidStudio create new java module compile error

Tags: android-studio, java.util.scanner

i created new android project and then created java module

[new java module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TVEz.png)

write code

```
package com.example.lib;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("-----------> input a num please");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("----> num = "+num);

    }
}
```

run compile error

Execution failed for task ':lib:MyClass.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFLAB.png)

java module build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

app build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

jdk: jdk11
androidstudio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWlVb.png)

i add task but alway compile error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvwpG.png)

i change jdk11 to jdk8 also compile error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mcxh.png)